# Electron - ipcRenderer not working in main.js

Tags: javascript, electron

I just can't figure this out. If I'm correct, usually you use "ipcMain" in the main file (in my case main.js). But I use colon-ide, and ipcMain is defined somewhere else.
I want to create a new window. Everything I need to create a new window is in the main.js file, but the signal is somewhere else. So I need to send a 'create-window' signal to main.js. In fact, I'm sending it from a file, where ipcMain is defined.

And here's the problem:
When in main.js I use the following:

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
ipc.on('someSignal', function (event, structure) {
     console.log("something");
});
```

I get an error, that ipc in undefined.

When I use the following:

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;
ipc.on('someSignal', function (event, structure) {
    console.log("something");
});
```

Nothing happens. It doesn't listen, and I believe I should only have one ipcMain, so this must be wrong.

What am I doing wrong? If you need more code, just tell me.

To elaborate, let me show you this:
I've got a **functions.js** file, where the event is invoked. Please ignore the "structure" variable.

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;

function someFunction() {
    console.log("function is invoked");
    let structure = 0;
    mainWindow.webContents.send('someSignal', structure);
}
```

"someFunction" is being invoked at some point - I get that "function is invoked" message in console, so this part works.

In **editor.js** the ipcRenderer is defined, and if I place the listener function here:

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

ipc.on('someSignal', function (event, structure) {
    console.log("something");
});
```

It works. "something" gets printed out.

But, I need to add the listener in **main.js** file, because that's where my function for creating new windows is. But the listener doesn't work there. If I use ipcRenderer it stays undefined and throws an error if I do the ipc.on function. If I use ipcMain it gets defined (typeof returns an object), so looks like this is what I have to use. But nothing happens.

Is this because I'm trying to send messages between 2 ipcMain? I might try to use a global function as a work around.

Comment: How are you invoking the event? You should show the use-case as well, as with the code you currently show, you only define a listener without sending an event that triggers it. Or is exactly the way of invoking it your question? There is also a short section showing an example of how to do that on [Electron's Quick Start Guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start#electron-api).

Comment: I've edited the question, please check it out. I'm omitting parts of the code that I believe are not relevant. Let me know, if you'd prefer the full code.

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase the question. How do I access the main file's functions from a renderer, if ipcMain is located in a different file than main? Either I'm terribly mislead about everything, or the globals don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the `require("electron")` API in the BrowserWindow, you need to enable `nodeIntegration` in the constructor.

```js
var myWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width:600,
  height:400,
  // --- below here ---
  webPreferences:{
    nodeIntegration:true
  }
  // --- above here ---
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, that's not it, I've already had nodeIntegration enabled. Also, creating the new window works, if I call it directly from the main.js file, but that's not what I want.

I've edited my question, to remove unnecessary information, like let's even forget that I'm trying to open a new window. Let's say I simply want to print something to the console.